# What is known about the minimal absolute value in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields, algebraic-integers

Here $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is the ring of integers of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, where $\zeta_n$ is the $n$th root of unity. In my mind $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ looks like a grid in the complex plane (is that clear/known?). In particular an element $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\setminus \{0\}$ with minimal absolute value $|\alpha| > 0$ should exists. Are there results about this minimal absolute value $|\alpha|$? In particular are there lower bounds on it with respect to $n$?

Comment: Integers in cyclotomic fields are not lattice-like: say $\frac{\sqrt{3}\pm i}{2}$ is 12th root of unity. $n+m\sqrt{3}$ is in the cyclotomic field and can be arbitrarily small

Comment: In general, for $n\ge 5$, we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}] > 2$, so $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ cannot be a $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice.

Comment: @Mastrem Does that imply, that for $n \geq 5$ there are always elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\setminus\{0\}$ with arbitrarily small absolute value?

Comment: It does. If you want to prove it, the contrapositive is probably the easiest way to do so: Show that  if $A\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an additive subgroup such that there exists an $\epsilon>0$  with $B_\epsilon(0)\cap A = \{0\}$, then $A=\omega_1\mathbb{Z}+\omega_2\mathbb{Z}$ for some $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Mastrem Perfect, thank you!

Comment: For $n> 6,\Re(\zeta_n)>1/2$ and so $|\zeta_n-1|< 1,\lim_{k\to \infty} |(\zeta_n-1)^k|=0$.

For $n=5$ you can look at $\zeta_{10}$.

It remains to check $n=1,2,3,4,6$.